# PHP Simple Html Dom extract multiple tags from one class

Tags: php, xml, simple-html-dom

I am a newbie to use simple html dom with php and I am struggling to extract multiple html tags from one class. I have multiple blocks of html like this in a single page

```
    <div class="file-right"> 
         <a href="/secrets-of-the-millionaire-mind-tomocubcom-e17682584.html" class="ai-similar" data-id="17682584" data-loc="3">
           <h2><b>Secrets</b> of the <b>Millionaire</b> <b>Mind</b> - TOMOCUB.COM</h2>
         </a>
           <span class="fi-pagecount">223 Pages</span>
           <span class="fi-year">2005</span>
           <span class="fi-size hidemobile">1015 KB</span>
         </div>
     2 - <b>Secrets</b> of the <b>Millionaire</b> <b>Mind</b> and your achievement of <b>success</b>. As you’ve probably fo&nbsp;...
   </div>
```

and from each block this html I want to extract

1. href link
2. the plain text in  tags
3. each of the 3 span's element text

I have been doing it in php but getting errors again and again. This is the code what i have uptill now

```
$html = @str_get_html($response);
$allblocks=$html->find('div.file-right'); //this selects all file-right blocks
if(isset($allblocks)){
   foreach($allblocks as $singleblock){
      echo $singleblock->plaintext; // but i get an error here PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion

   }
}
```

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build up the various layers of taking the HTML apart, you started by finding the `<div>` tag.  You can from that find the `<a>` tag within this `<div>` and then get the href attribute (using `->href`).  This code assumes that there is only one `<a>` tag, so rather than a `foreach` I just say use the first one (using `[0]`).

The `<span>` tags is a similar process, but as there are repeated elements, this time it uses a `foreach`.  This code outputs the class attribute and the contents of the span.

```
$html = str_get_html($response);
$allblocks=$html->find('div.file-right'); //this selects all file-right blocks
if ( count($allblocks) > 0 ){
    foreach ( $allblocks as $block )    {
        $anchor = $block->find("a");
        echo "href=".$anchor[0]->href.PHP_EOL;
        echo "text=".$anchor[0]->plaintext.PHP_EOL;
        $spans = $block->find("span");
        foreach ( $spans as $span ) {
            echo "span=".$span->class."=".$span->plaintext.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that when in your original code you used `isset($allblocks)`, as the line before set it's value - even if it didn't find anything it will still have a value.  In this code I use `count()` to check if anything is returned by the previous call to `find()`.

With your sample HTML, wrapped only in a minumum page, the output is...

```
href=/secrets-of-the-millionaire-mind-tomocubcom-e17682584.html
text=            Secrets of the Millionaire Mind - TOMOCUB.COM          
span=fi-pagecount=223 Pages 
span=fi-year=2005 
span=fi-size hidemobile=1015 KB
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. I am really very grateful to but I just wanted to know the one last thing how can i extract each span element by its class name like I just used that php code $count = $block->find('span[class=fi-pagecount]')->plaintext.PHP_EOL; but it again gives me error of array to string conversion

Comment: As `find()` returns an array of matches, you need to use `[0]` to say the first one - `$count = $block->find('span[class=fi-pagecount]')[0]->plaintext;`

Comment: Thank you so much it really means a lot